# How to print the value of std::any in lldb

Tags: c++17, lldb

for example:

```cpp
std::any a = 1
```

in lldb:

```bash
(lldb) p a
(std::any) $1 = {
  __h = 0x000000010000d200 (main`std::__1::__any_imp::_SmallHandler<int>::__handle(std::__1::__any_imp::_Action, std::__1::any const*, std::__1::any*, std::type_info const*, void const*) at any:350)
  __s = {
    __ptr = 0x0000000000000001
    __buf = (__lx = "\U00000001")
  }
}
```

so that I know the value of a is an integer, but how can I print it out? It seems unlikely to execute `std::any_cast<int>(a)` in lldb CLI.

Comment: Functionally, representing complex data types to be more user-friendly is handled by Summary and Synthetic Child providers in lldb, described here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html.  lldb has formatters for at least the clang & gcc standard library types, but there have been lots of new constructs coming in recently people are still catching up.  If there was a way to get the actual type from the std::any, a Child provider should be straightforward, but I don't see how you get that.

Comment: @JimIngham I tried this, and it works fine in lldb-15 and libcxx-15. https://gist.github.com/TsaiHao/a0abaaa7272c917d5fc00e2bdc676969

Answer (score 0):

According to libcxx-15 implementation of `std::any`, I can get a's __buf pointer, reinterpret it as "Type" pointer, and print value. This should work for small types whose size is smaller than 24 bytes in a 64bits machine.

But it is highly dependent on the compiler and hardware.

To express it in cpp:

```cpp
std::cout << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;
std::any s = std::string("hello");

char* p = (char*)(&s);
p += 8;
std::string* str = (std::string*)p;
std::cout << *str << std::endl;
```